# Overiding onResume method in android not working in every fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onresume

I'm creating android app that have 3 fragments and I want refresh data every time I come back to the fragment. So, I override `onResume()` method in every fragment and add system out print to onresume to check if it's worked correctly.

But when I navigate to 2nd fragment it shows the add system out print of fragment 3 onresume. when I go to fragment 3 it not showing any add system out print. but when I came back to 2nd again it shows add system out print of fragment 1.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in your `ViewPager`. It is the expected behaviour of the adapter that only neighbouring fragments are created. If you do not want this behaviour use `FragmentPagerAdapter`. But be aware of the memory taken up by all the fragments.

Comment: from where can i change that

Comment: make your viewpager's adapter extend `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Comment: i did..but same problem still occurs

Comment: if it didn't work, create method in the fragment and call it directly from the activity using the reference of the fragment.

Comment: do you mean for the refresh the fragment

Comment: do whatever you were trying to do inside the onResume of fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Make your fragments implement an interface:

```
public interface Listener {
    void resume()
}
```

Make your activity implement `OnPageChangeListener`:

`viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);`

and then do the following:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    ((Listener) mAdapter.getItem(position)).resume();
}
```

Comment: i added Listener in fragment and onPageSelected in MainActivity. but onPageSelected show as never used.

Comment: did you add `addOnPageChangeListener` on your `ViewPager` ?

Comment: No. overide of the onPageSelected shows as method dose not overide method from its super class.

Comment: i add addOnPageChangeListener on your ViewPager. still i cant override the onPageSelected methed in MainActivity

Comment: do you have something like `public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnPageChangeListener` ?

Comment: no. if you are not busy can you fix me this through TeamViwer

Comment: i implement the  OnPageChangeListener  ti my main activity and my activity changed to abstract.is it ok

Comment: no there's no errors.if i want add onresume in all 3 tabs do i have to do i have to add all 3 Listener of tabs inside onpaged selected

Comment: i remove the abstract class and implement other others of the OnPageChangeListener  no errors and run the app.when app start it shows a error as  "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.aser.tabtest.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnAdapterChangeListener"

error shows in here
 mViewPager.addOnAdapterChangeListener((ViewPager.OnAdapterChangeListener) this);